# Why would a Wordpress site have all content built in PHP files?

Tags: wordpress

Picked up a new client. Site is built on Wordpress.  Previous developer built nearly all page content in their custom theme's PHP files.

In other words, the theme's "page.php" file contains virtually all the markup for each of the site's pages. Each individual page's back-end page editor appears empty, except for *some* of the page text. No markup, no widgets, no custom fields. No dedicated, page-specific php files either.

Pages are differentiated within page.php using:

```
elseif ( is_page("27") )
```

I've never come across this approach before. Why might someone do this?

Comment: We have no idea. It could be laziness, incompetence, or something else. Only the original developer will know for sure.

Comment: too good to use simple and standard method, must code everything in php file. lol 
charge more or leave that project alone (rock)

Comment: The only major advantage I can think of would be **if** it improved loading speed, but I don't know if that's indeed the case.

Other possible advantage would be that it's easier to make bulk changes. One could edit multiple pages from within a single file. But it seems like a bad tradeoff.